# UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton not shown in cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using tableView grouped Style. my DisclosureButton is not shown in my table cell.what I am missing?

THANKS

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView 
                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
     reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];


}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

   // cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];

   cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;



return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does disclosureButton show in non-editing mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table seems to be in editing state. You should set the accessoryType in editing mode.

```
cell.editingAccessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Comment: Great.. I think this is perfect answer, My DetailDisclosureButton is shown now :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` hide the accessory button in editing mode.
So if you want to display it, you will need to customize the `UITableViewCell`.
Or you can do it like the answer given by 
**Vito Limandibhrata**